# File Handling and Strings(Log in system)

Tags: c

I am creating a log in system. Just the basic, username and pass.

```
=====Log in===
user: abcd
pass: ****
==============
```

max 4 alphanumeric characters.

```
struct account
{
 user[5];
 pass[5];
}s;
```

For example in my `database.txt` file I already have this.

```
abcd //user
1234 //pass
```

So in the main its like this:

```
main()
{
 FILE *fp;
 fp=fopen("account.txt","r");
 char user[5],pass[5];
 printf("enter user: ");
 gets(user);
 printf("enter pass: "); 
 pass[0] = getch();
 printf("*");                       //doing this for 
 pass[1] = getch();                 //password security
 printf("*");                       //asterisk(*)
 pass[2] = getch();
 printf("*");
 pass[3] = getch();
 printf("*");
 pass[4] = '0';
 getch();

 while(fread(&s,sizeof(s),1,fp)==1);
 {
  if(ferror(fp))
  {
    printf("error");
  }
  else if (strcmp(s.user,user) == 0 && strcmp(s.pass,pass) == 0)
  {
   printf("success!");
  }
  else
  {
   printf("invalid");
  }
 }
 getch();
}
```

problem is it is not working. When I put the correct pass it will always say invalid. but when I use

`gets(pass);` rather than the `pass[0]=getch();` it works perfect.

Is this the correct way of doing the password security and reading it?

Comment: Have you verified that you are reading data from the file correctly?

Comment: @ScottHunter Yes, got no problem when using  gets(pass); .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, this is not a particularly good idea, as it is extremely insecure.  Several decades of lessons on how not to do this have been learned by the industry, and you are on track to re-learn those the painful way.

As to your specific problem,  you are not null terminating the `pass` array before running a null-terminated string comparison on it.

Declare it with 5 elements, and set the fifth - pass[4] - to 0.

Comment: Edited it, but still it is not working. Thinking that fread is not the correct way for this. Maybe you have other way of doing this?

Comment: Actually you should set the last element to 0, which is equal to '\0' which is very different from '0'. Read more about ascii and string representation in computer if you don't know the difference.

Comment: Got it. I remembered the null terminator '\0'.

Comment: What is the best way of doing this btw?

Comment: Indeed, I said 0, not '0'